# Facebook check in android tutorial

Tags: android, facebook

I want my app users to check in from my app to their facebook account. Is that possible using the facebook sdk?

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen the Hackbook for Android? http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/hackbook/

See over here an example for the Check-in

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/examples/Hackbook/src/com/facebook/android/Places.java